# c# Union Operator

Tags: c#, casting, operators, union

**Scenario**
I have three IEnumerable lists - `IEnumerable<Dog>`, `IEnumerable<Cat>` and `IEnumerable<Horse>`.
I want them in all in a single `IEnumerable<NameColor>`.
I have a `public static explicit operator NameColor` defined on each of the Dog, Cat and Horse objects to allow me to cast them to `NameColor`

So:

```
IEnumerable<NameColor> list = dogs as IEnumerable<NameColor>;
list = list.Union(cats as IEnumerable<NameColor>);
list = list.Union(horses as IEnumerable<NameColor>);
```

However, this doesnt work. I get the error `Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: first` but I dont see a parameter called `first` even being an option?!

Comment: Perhaps Union needs .First(). Are you sure none of these lists are empty?

Comment: As an aside - note that `Union` isn't quite the same as "I want them all in..." - you might mean `Concat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

```
var list = dogs.Select(d => (NameColor)d)
               .Union(cats.Select(c => (NameColor)c))
               .Union(horses.Select(h => (NameColor)h));
```

Comment: I wonder if `Enumerable.Cast()` would work with conversions. Edit: checked source and realised it wouldn't as it merely does an `as` cast of the `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 3):

`first` is the implicit "this" parameter of `Enumerable.Union`. It's throwing an exception because the `as` operator's result is `null`.

Basically the problem is that having a conversion operator for `Dog` *doesn't* mean that you can treat an `IEnumerable<Dog>` as an `IEnumerable<NameColor>`. Use `Select` instead, basically.

There are actually two reasons behind your conversion not working:

- `as` doesn't apply conversions anyway, so if you do:

  ```
  NameColor nameColor = dog as NameColor;
  ```

  that would still leave `nameColor` as null.
- Just because there's a conversion between *element* types doesn't mean that conversion is applied to the *collection* types themselves. Generic variance only works for reference type conversions, which are *representation-preserving*.